# Additional values in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I created the following code in Java (1.8.0.121) for parsing of iMatrix array into matrixOutput one.
Once I run it I noticed that appears additional values in cells 1,0 and 1,1.

Could someone advice me how should I change to avoid such additions for other arrays (I plan a generic code which will take different arrays in format like iMatrix array)
    public class Dbg {

```
private static int[][] matrixOutput = { { 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 4, 0 }, 
                                        { 1, 2, 0, 0, 5 }, 
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
private static int[][] iMatrix = {
        {1, -1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, -1, 0},
        {-1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, -1, 1, 0, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 1, 0, -1},
        {0, 0, 0, 2, 0}};
private static int i = 0;
private static int j = 0;
private static int val = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] list = new int[5][5];

    for (int m = 0; m < iMatrix.length; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < iMatrix[m].length; n++) {
            if (iMatrix[m][n] == 1){
                i = n;
            }
            if (iMatrix[m][n] == -1){   
                j = n;
                val = n + 1;

            }
            list[i][j] = val;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(list[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
}
```

Insead of MatrixOutput it gives me the following result:

```
02000
12040
12005
00000
00000
```

When I changed places for 3 and 4 rows viceverso I saw that value 1 from 1,0 disappears. All values from iMatrix are stored correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag indicating which programming language you are using.

Comment: Also this is a good time to learn how to use a debugger

Answer (score 0):

Initialize val = 0 inside the 2nd for loop while creating list. Because your code will print previous value of 'val' if iMatrix[m][n] is not equal to '1' or '-1'.

Code:

```
for (int m = 0; m < iMatrix.length; m++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < iMatrix[m].length; n++) 
    {
        val = 0;
        if (iMatrix[m][n] == 1)
        {
            i = n;
        }
        if (iMatrix[m][n] == -1)
        {   
            j = n;
            val = n + 1;
        }
        list[i][j] = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Prints array of 0

Comment: Why appears values for 1,0 and 1,1?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[][] matrixOutput = { 
        { 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 4, 0 }, 
        { 1, 2, 0, 0, 5 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
private static int[][] iMatrix = { 
    { 1, -1, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, -1, 0 },
    { -1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, -1, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 0, -1 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 2, 0 } };


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] list = new int[5][5];

    for (int m = 0; m < iMatrix.length; m++) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int val = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < iMatrix[m].length; n++) {

            if (iMatrix[m][n] == 1) {
                i = n;
            }
            if (iMatrix[m][n] == -1) {
                j = n;
                val = n+1;

            }
            list[i][j] = val;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(list[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but [2,0] was missed

Comment: I need to understand your task. Please describe what your code should do.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote my code with adding a validation for printing and a variable flag.

```
private static int[][] iMatrix = {
        {1, -1, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0, -1, 0},
        {-1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, -1, 1, 0, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 1, 0, -1},
        {0, 0, 0, 2, 0}};
private static int i = 0;
private static int j = 0;
private static int val = 0;
private static int flag = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] list = new int[5][5];

    for (int m = 0; m < iMatrix.length; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < iMatrix[m].length; n++) {
            if (iMatrix[m][n] == 1){
                i = n;
                flag++;
            }
            if (iMatrix[m][n] == -1){   
                j = n;
                val = n + 1;
                flag++;
            }

            if (flag == 2){
                list[i][j] = val;
                flag = 0;
            }


        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(list[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

output became like following:

```
02000
00040
12005
00000
00000
```